# Retrieving parts of a URI by meaning

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, uri

I'm writing a custom URI parser (which extends [GenericUriParser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.genericuriparser.aspx)) in order to allow my program to deal with unix/linux-style `smb://` and `nfs://` URIs.

In order to do this, I need to override the [GetComponents](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uriparser.getcomponents.aspx) method which is responsible for filling in the various properties of the `Uri` object (e.g. host, path, absolute URI ...). This is where I get stuck. I have absolutely no idea on how to 'split' the input string by meaning.

Examples of valid input (smb only, nfs is even more complicated):

```
smb://hostname/public/example.txt
smb://username:password@hostname/public/example.txt
smb://10.0.0.1/public
```

Where do I even begin to solve this problem?

Comment: Regexes seem to be the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you to use `Regex`. For the given url in question, the regex pattern could be something like this:

```
var pattern = 
    "^smb:\/\/((?<user>[\w-]+):(?<pwd>[\w-]+)@)?(?<host>[a-z0-9\.-]+)(?<path>.+)$";
```

You can match a url with pattern and extract parts by name. E.g.

```
var regex = new Regex(pattern);
var match = regex.Match(url);
if(match.Success) {
    // the url is smb
    var username = match.Groups["user"].Value;
    var password = match.Groups["pwd"].Value;
    var hostname = match.Groups["host"].Value;
    var path = match.Groups["path"].Value;
}
```

For the given urls in question, we will have these variables:

```
// smb://hostname/public/example.txt
username: string.Empty
password: string.Empty
hostname: hostname
path: /public/example.txt

// smb://username:password@hostname/public/example.txt
username: username
password: password
hostname: hostname
path: /public/example.txt

// smb://10.0.0.1/public
username: string.Empty
password: string.Empty
hostname: 10.0.0.1
path: /public
```

The given pattern is a simple and demo pattern. So, if you want to go this way, you should create complex and complete and correct patterns to code get worked correctly. Let me know if you have any question or problem.

Comment: I didn't know you could assign names to regex groups. This does make things a lot easier than calling regex.split and looping through the resulting array (facepalm, I know). Thank you, I'm sure this is exactly what I was looking for.